# Razor MVC 3, Dropdownlist in ViewBag - Help understanding this piece of code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag, html-select

I'm new to MVC and I'm having trouble understanding a piece of code.
I created a new controller and with it all the CRUD methods and view - auto-generated by visual studio - and I could not understand one part of the code.

See, in the controller it set a SelectList from the database and put it in a ViewBag like this:
Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{    
    ViewBag.TypeID = new SelectList(db.PlacementTypes, "TypeID", "Description");
    return View();
}
```

And in the View it's like this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeID, "PlacementType")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeID)
</div>
```

What I don't understand is. Where the heck is the SelectList comming from? Since I don't see a call to ViewBag.

I would expect something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("TypeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.TypeID)
```

That's my doubt. How does MVC know where to find the right list without specifying the ViewBag??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FACTS:

- **ViewBag** is one among the cool features included in  [ASP.NET MVC 3 - Release Candidate 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx) earlier announced by Scott Guthrie. 
  It is used to pass data from the Controller to Views same as you use ViewData[] dictionary.
- What is great and nice about ViewBag(aside from its name) is that its a **dynamic** type which means you can dynamically get/set values and add any number of additional fields without need of strongly-typed classes.
  (reference:[http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx)](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx)

In your example you dont have to cast the SelectList ViewBag since ViewBag is a **dynamic** type.
The SelectList part function of TypeID was already been done on your **Controller** part.

So calling the TypeID alone on your create will already trigger everything that is under to it.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer toguether with @heads5150's helpped me understand a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have named your DropDownList "TypeID" since there was no SelectList provided the code will search the Model for an item called "TypeID".

Therefore the call to ViewBag.TypeID to get the SelectList is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation man. As I'm not very familiar with MVC eveything just seem to happen so magically.